# Need to have transaction id from pay key PayPal

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, paypal

I have successfully integrated PayPal into my iOS application using PayPal MPL library.
But the problem is how to get the transaction id from paykey which i get from callback method of PayPal.

i have tried this way but getting error of invalid request.

```
- (void)paymentSuccessWithKey:(NSString *)payKey andStatus:(PayPalPaymentStatus)paymentStatus
{

 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://svcs.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/PaymentDetails"]];

//NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/PaymentDetails"]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    NSString *parameterString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"payKey=%@&requestEnvelope.errorLanguage=%@",payKey,@"en_US"];

    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [parameterString length]];

    [theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

    //do post request for parameter passing
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    [theRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    //passing key as a http header request
    [theRequest addValue:api_username forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID"];

    //passing key as a http header request
    [theRequest addValue:api_password forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD"];

    [theRequest addValue:api_signature forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE"];

    [theRequest addValue:@"JSON" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT"];

    [theRequest addValue:@"JSON" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT"];

    [theRequest addValue:app_id forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID"];

    [theRequest setHTTPBody: [parameterString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *err;
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:&response error:&err];

    NSString* s = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *result = [s JSONValue] ;

}
```

i need to save the transaction id on the backend of my application for future references.
Need to know how to get it asap.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks & Regards
Pankaj

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about iOS but for andorid , we implement PayPalResultDelegate , Serializable interface , in a class like . i am sharing my code :

```
class ResultDelegate implements PayPalResultDelegate, Serializable 
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 10001L;

    PaypalDetailImplementation ob = new PaypalDetailImplementation() ;

    public void onPaymentSucceeded(String payKey, String paymentStatus) 
    {
        ob.resultTitle = "SUCCESS";
        ob.resultInfo = "You have successfully completed your transaction.";
        ob.resultExtra = "Key: " + payKey;

        this.displayInformation("onPaymentSucceeded", ob.resultTitle, ob.resultInfo, ob.resultExtra) ;
    }

    public void onPaymentFailed(String paymentStatus, String correlationID,String payKey, String errorID, String errorMessage) 
    {
        ob.resultTitle = "FAILURE";
        ob.resultInfo = errorMessage;
        ob.resultExtra = "Error ID: " + errorID + "\nCorrelation ID: "+ correlationID + "\nPay Key: " + payKey;

        this.displayInformation("onPaymentFailed", ob.resultTitle, ob.resultInfo, ob.resultExtra) ;
    }

    public void onPaymentCanceled(String paymentStatus) 
    {
        ob.resultTitle = "CANCELED";
        ob.resultInfo = "The transaction has been cancelled.";
        ob.resultExtra = "";

        this.displayInformation("onPaymentCanceled", ob.resultTitle, ob.resultInfo, ob.resultExtra) ;
    }

    public void displayInformation ( String msg , String resultTitle , String resultInfo , String resultExtra )
    {
        Log.i("Result as message : ",msg);
        Log.i(resultTitle,"tushar:onPaymentSucceeded");
        Log.i(resultInfo,"tushar:onPaymentSucceeded");
        Log.i(resultExtra,"tushar:onPaymentSucceeded");

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but as far as i understand above code does not yield the transaction id. the only thing it gave is PayKey which i already have.

Answer (score 0):

First, it's critically important to make sure that you don't ship an app with the API password & signature. Otherwise a malicious user could disassemble your app, recover the credentials and perform arbitrary operations to your account. [Read more about verifying a payment.](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/)

But, assuming that you implemented similar code on your server, it *should* work. What is the exact error that you're getting?

Comment: Thanks for your reply tomwhipple, i was already doing this but any how got my problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem solved my self.

I was making the X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT of JSON type but when i changed it to NV i start edgetting transaction id.

Thanks to all for their answers.

Comment: What is NV here ? As you said you changed request format from JSON to NV.

Comment: @NishantTyagi NV is Name-Value format supported by PayPal